# Want to identify whether two discs touch each other

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, collision-detection

I have two discs that can move separately with the help of keyboard. The two discs represent two players and I want to code :

1. If disc1 touches disc2 then the size of disc2 reduces a little bit
2. Both the discs should not go out of the screen

Comment: I tried to detect collision of two discs and it is so confusing. I'm just a beginner in opengl. :-(

Comment: So far I have two discs that can move differently with wasd and arrow keys

Comment: This is a very simple geometry problem... what is common of all points inside a circle with respect to the center?

Answer (score 1):

Given that they're discs, collision detection is actually fairly simple and straightforward. Given two discs with radii R<sub>1</sub> and R<sub>2</sub>, if the distance between the centers of the two objects is less than or equal to R<sub>1</sub>+R<sub>2</sub>, then they've collided.

You can compute the distance between the two center points using the Pythagorean theorem: the distance equals the square root of the sum of the delta X squared and delta Y squared.

If you're doing this very often, you probably want to avoid that square root. Fortunately that's pretty easy: square the sum of the two radii, and compare that to the sum of the squares of delta X and delta Y.

Comment: void disc1(){ 
 
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        float x1,y1,x2,y2;
float angle;
double radius=0.1;
 
x1 = 0.5,y1=0.6;
glColor3f(0.0,1.0,0.0);
 
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
glVertex2f(x1,y1);
 
for (angle=1.0f;angle<180.0f;angle+=0.2)
{
    x2 = x1+sin(angle)*radius; 
    y2 = y1+cos(angle)*radius;
    glVertex2f(x2,y2);
}
    glEnd();

}

Comment: @user2051037: You probably want to edit the code into your question so it'll be formatted (and more visible to others reading and potentially answering the question). Ultimately, however, drawing the disc(s) and doing collision detection are normally separate.

Comment: I was wondering how to get the radius and all. Like i said i'm very new to graphics

Comment: @user2051037: You're specifying the radius as `radius` in the code above.

Comment: For drawing each disc I use each separate function.

Comment: How to find the distance between the centers of two objects?

Comment: @user2051037: As mentioned in the answer above, the Pythagorean theorm is probably the most obvious way.

Comment: How can I prevent the discs from overlapping each other?

Comment: @user2051037: stop moving them closer to each other, or shrink one/both to keep them from overlapping.